# How to combine 3 Union Select statements with 3 other Union Select Statements using inner join

Tags: mysql

```
 Select STID, STUID, Role from st_officer_assign
   UNION
   Select STID, STUID, Role from st_nco_assign
   UNION
   Select STID, STUID, Role from st_troop_assign
```

I want to inner join the above union results with the below union results on STID;

```
  Select STID, Rank, Gender, ServiceYears, Height, Weight, DutyCategory, DutyStatus from stormtroopers_officer
   UNION
   Select STID, Rank, Gender, ServiceYears, Height, Weight, DutyCategory, DutyStatus from stormtroopers_nco
   UNION
   Select STID, Rank, Gender, ServiceYears, Height, Weight, DutyCategory, DutyStatus from stormtroopers_troop;
```

First 3 union select statements have 3 columns: STID, STUID and Role.
Last 3 union select statments have 8 columns: STID, Rank, Gender, ServiceYears, Height, Weight, DutyCategory, DutyStatus

The common column in both statements is the STID column. I want to ultimately comibine them using inne join to display these columns:
STID, STUID, Role, Rank, Gender, ServiceYears, Height, Weight, DutyCategory, DutyStatus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the two set of union as subquery

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from (
     Select STID, STUID, Role from st_officer_assign
     UNION
     Select STID, STUID, Role from st_nco_assign
     UNION
     Select STID, STUID, Role from st_troop_assign

) t1 
inner join  (
     Select STID, Rank, Gender, ServiceYears, Height, Weight, DutyCategory, DutyStatus from stormtroopers_officer
     UNION
     Select STID, Rank, Gender, ServiceYears, Height, Weight, DutyCategory, DutyStatus from stormtroopers_nco
     UNION
     Select STID, Rank, Gender, ServiceYears, Height, Weight, DutyCategory, DutyStatus from stormtroopers_troop

) t2 on t1.STID = t2.STID
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you one of the option is using a subquery. Here's the code.

```
select *
from (Select STID, STUID, Role from st_officer_assign
        UNION
      Select STID, STUID, Role from st_nco_assign
        UNION
      Select STID, STUID, Role from st_troop_assign)qry1
inner join ( Select STID, Rank, Gender, ServiceYears, Height, Weight, DutyCategory, DutyStatus from stormtroopers_officer
               UNION
             Select STID, Rank, Gender, ServiceYears, Height, Weight, DutyCategory, DutyStatus from stormtroopers_nco
               UNION
               Select STID, Rank, Gender, ServiceYears, Height, Weight, DutyCategory, DutyStatus from stormtroopers_troop)qry2 on qry1.STID = qry2.STID
```

You can select the columns which you want from qry1 and qry2.
More on subqueries here: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-subquery/